# maven: how to fix dependency issue in intellji

Tags: apache, intellij-idea

The following is the maven dependencies i want to access in my project pom.xml but it's unable to recognize that one,  it's showing org.apache.commons.math4: 4.0 snapshot not found.

please, help me how can i fix it?

```
    **<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll just need to add the repository config:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>apache</id>
        <name>apache_snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repository.apache.org/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And after that you need to run maven command:

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Flag **-U** Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories

Because you want to use the SNAPSHOT version. Snapshot version can change every day.

It should help you, I've checked just now.

Answer (score 1):

According to maven repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/), there is no math4.

What you need to use is math3:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: There's a math4: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/dependency-info.html  Maven doesn't have it, but Apache does. See the accepted answer.

Comment: The math3 solution just worked for me in Eclipse.
(I did not bother adding the repositories)